# How do I compile glossaries using vim-tex?

Tags: neovim, plugin-vim-latex

I initially asked this on the LaTeX stack exchange, but there seems to be little input:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/712127/compiling-glossaries-with-neovim

TL;DR: how do I set up the compiler to work with the glossaries package.

Currently I'm using vim-tex with the  tectonic compiler to write pdfs using LaTeX.
I'm trying to compile a document with glossaries (which uses makeindex). How do I set up the compiler to run makeindex automatically (or not; if there is a way to run it manually, I can live with that too)?

Current init.vim setup:

```
let g:vimtex_compiler_method = 'tectonic'
let g:vimtex_compiler_tectonic = {
        \ 'out_dir' : '',
        \ 'hooks' : [],
        \ 'options' : [
        \   '--synctex'
        \ ],
        \}
```

Sample document I want to compile:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,final]{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{tplgy:topology}{
    name ={Topology},
    description = {Topology}    
}
\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is indeed a LaTeX question :-|

Comment: Please don't crosspost. Either keep this question or the one on LeTex SE. Thank you.

Comment: Hm, given the vimtex refs in the [tex.se] post, perhaps it should be migrated here.

Comment: I'm choosing to close this because it doesn't provide enough detail. Please either [edit] to include the relevant detail from the [tex.se] post, or see about migrating the other post here (you can work with [tex.se] mods to make that happen, I think).